# Azure ADB2C Add Federated Users via Graph API

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I have a similar scenario as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63258255/pre-create-federated-users-in-azure-b2c-using-graph) question.

My question is: How can I get the federated user's `issuerAssignedId`?

For example, I thought that if I have a AD Tenant as an identity provider, then I can make
a Graph Request querying by email or something and then get the `objectId` of that user. But this seems a bit strange since I could have multiple identity providers. I would have to implement this logic for every `IP`. Is this the case? What does the `signUp` flow do under the hood? (since that's the one fetching the `issuerAssignedId`)

Comment: issuerAssignedId is usually gotten from the sub claim that the identity providers return. In some cases you can know that in advance and in some cases you can't :\

Comment: Ohh, that makes sense. But I guess you can't manage to get that programmatically, right?

Comment: Yeah the sub claim is "pairwise unique", meaning it is unique per user but also different per app. And you can't get it through APIs in advance. If you can configure it to use oid claim instead, then that would be the objectId that you can get.

Comment: What do you mean in advance? And by using `oid` you mean configuring the `Identity Provider` to use `oid` as `User ID` mapping? If that's so, I already did that. So basically the federated users in my B2C have the `Issuer assigned ID` equal to the `Object ID` from the `Identity Provider`. At the moment of creating a federated user, I need the `Issuer assigned ID` so that's why I thought about using `GraphAPI` for my IP, but I would like that to be done automatically somehow.

Comment: Oh ok! The issuerAssignedId should be the objectId then. You'll need an app registration in the AAD you are using as an IdP that has rights to read all users as itself. Then you could query MS Graph API for the user objectIds and assign them to user entities in your B2C tenant. Those should then allow the federated users to just sign in.

Comment: I see, that was what I was thinking. Sad that there is no way around it, because everytime I would add an IDP I would also need to update my backend logic to add that piece of code for fetching `issuerAssignedId`.